# Button which is part of Multi-step of Contact Form 7 is not displaying correctly on mobile version

Tags: css, wordpress, button, styles, contact-form

I have created a multi-step form in Contact Form 7. It works well, all good except that on mobile device (I have tested only on iPhone) button is not the style I want. It is necessary that it inherits my website's theme style.

[image: Screenshot from iPhone where buttons have different style]

On the picture 2 buttons are shown, button back is part of Contact Form, the other is from website, so they have two different sources. I understand the reason behind. On desktop all works well as I customized it with CSS but for mobile, have no idea what is the best way to do it. I assume it has to do something with iOS webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    input {
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
    }
```

or even just

```
    input {
       -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

Another option, if that didn't work, is to add [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/). This is what worked for me, but it seems most people were able to solve it with the above code.